# Is adding conditions to a reducer is an anti pattern?

Tags: redux

I have a cart items in my store and i want to check if the user added the same item with the same color and size.

If so i just want to increase the quantity, if not just add it but it creates kinda akward reducer and i wanted to know if this considered as an anti pattern and if so, what can we do to simplify it

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
      // Check to see if we already have the same product
      // with the same color and size in our cart
      const productIndex = state.products
        .findIndex(product => product._id === action.product._id
          && product.size === action.product.size
          && product.color === action.product.color);

      // if we have it already increase the quantity  
      if (productIndex !== -1) {
        const updatedProduct = {
          ...state.products[productIndex],
          quantity: state.products[productIndex].quantity + action.product.quantity,
        };

        return {
          ...state,
          products: [
            ...state.products.slice(0, productIndex),
            updatedProduct,
            ...state.products.slice(productIndex + 1),
          ],
        };
      }

      // if not just save it
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [...state.products, action.product],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's absolutely *not* an anti-pattern.  [Reducers can, and should, do a lot more than just `return {...state, ...action.payload}`](https://redux.js.org/faq/codestructure#how-should-i-split-my-logic-between-reducers-and-action-creators-where-should-my-business-logic-go).  Now, what logic you put in a reducer is up to you, as well as what abstractions you choose to use in the process.

If you're concerned about writing [nested immutable update logic](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns), then I'd suggest looking at the [`immer` immutable update library](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer/).  I'd also suggest trying out our new [`redux-starter-kit` package](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-starter-kit), which uses `immer` internally.